# What's causing Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, runtime-error

I am getting this specific error, help would be appreciated

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
>
> Object required: 'openRecordSet(...)'
>
> /admin/users/affiliates/process.asp, line 47

Line 47 is `Set objRecordset    = openRecordset(strSQL, objConnection)`

```
<%  
SetUserLevel(" 2 ")

If (InStr(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"), "://jim/admin/users/affiliate") = 0) Then
    Response.Redirect( "/admin/users/affiliate/" )
End If

Dim objConnection, objRecordset, strSQL, Affiliate_ID

If (IsEmpty(Request.Form("Affiliate_ID")) Or RTrim(Request.Form("Affiliate_ID")) = "") Then
    Affiliate_ID = 0
Else
    Affiliate_ID = prepareSQL(Request.Form("Affiliate_ID"))
End If

strSQL = "EXEC sp_User_Add_Affiliate " & _
        Session("User_ID") & ", '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("First_Name")) & "', '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("Middle_Initial")) & "', '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("Last_Name")) & "', '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("Email_Address")) & "', '" & _
        Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") & "', " & _
        Session.SessionID & ", '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("Address_1")) & "', '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("Address_2")) & "', '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("City")) & "', '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("State")) & "', '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("Zip")) & "', '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("Country")) & "', '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("Phone")) & "', '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("Phone_Extension")) & "', '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("Fax")) & "', '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("Company")) & "', '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("Pay_To")) & "', '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("Tax_ID")) & "', '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("Tax_ID_Type")) & "', '" & _
        prepareSQL(Request.Form("Tax_Class")) & "', " & _
        Affiliate_ID & "," & _
        Request.Form("ID") & "," & _
        Request.Form("Approved")

Set objConnection   = openConnectionAdmin()
Set objRecordset    = openRecordset(strSQL, objConnection)

If objRecordset("Error") = "1" Then
    Response.Write objRecordset("Data")
    Response.End
End If

objRecordset.Close

Set objRecordset    = Nothing
Set objConnection   = Nothing

Response.Redirect ( "/admin/users/affiliates/" ) %>

Function openRecordSet(ByVal strSQL, ByRef objConnection) 
    On Error Resume Next 
    '   logSQL(strSQL) 
    Set openRecordset = objConnection.Execute(strSQL) 
    If err.Number <> 0 Then 
          'Response.Write Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description logError("ASP: openRecordset: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & ": " & strSQL) 
    '    Call displayErrorPage() 
    End If 
End Function
```

Comment: This isn't a .NET question; at a guess I'd say openConnectionAdmin() is returning Nothing. You need to look into what's happening in that method, possibly the connection string details are wrong.

Comment: This means you get an error executing the SQL. Silencing the error is BAD idea, remove the `On Error Resume Next` line and see what error you get. **Do not use `On Error Resume Next` without trapping the errors**!!

Answer (score 0):

The error typically is caused by using `Set` to indicate assignment of an object to a variable, but having a non-object for the right value:

```
>> Set v = New RegExp
>>                         [no news here are good news]
>> Set v = "a"
>>
Error Number:       424
Error Description:  Object required
```

So check your `openRecordset` function. Does it return a recordset by executing

```
Set openRecordset = ....
```

(mark the `Set`) for the given parameters?

**Update wrt comments:**

This test script:

```
Option Explicit

' How to test the type of a function's return value that should
' be an object but sometimes isn't. You can't assign the return value
' to a variable because of VBScript's disgusting "Set".
WScript.Echo "TypeName(openConnectionAdmin()): ", TypeName(openConnectionAdmin())
WScript.Echo "TypeName(openRecordset(...))   : ", TypeName(openRecordset("", objConnection))

' Trying to create a connection and a recordset
Dim objConnection : Set objConnection = openConnectionAdmin()
Dim objRecordset  : Set objRecordset  = openRecordset("", objConnection)

Function openConnectionAdmin()
' Set openConnectionAdmin = CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
  Set openConnectionAdmin = Nothing
End Function

' After removing the comments: Obviously this is a function that
' hides all errors; the programmer should be fed to the lions.
Function openRecordSet(ByVal strSQL, ByRef objConnection)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set openRecordset = objConnection.Execute(strSQL)
End Function
```

output:

```
TypeName(openConnectionAdmin()):  Connection
TypeName(openRecordset(...))   :  Empty
... Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'openRecordset(...)'
```

or

```
TypeName(openConnectionAdmin()):  Nothing
TypeName(openRecordset(...))   :  Empty
... Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'openRecordset(...)'
```

shows: By hiding every conceivable error in openRecordset() the function can return Empty (undetected!), which isn't an object and can't be assigned to a variable by using Set.

Comment: Here is my openRecordset function  `Function openRecordSet(ByVal strSQL, ByRef objConnection)
 On Error Resume Next

' logSQL(strSQL)
 Set openRecordset = objConnection.Execute(strSQL)

 If err.Number <> 0 Then
  'Response.Write Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  logError("ASP: openRecordset: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & ": " & strSQL)
'  Call displayErrorPage()
 End If

End Function `

Comment: It's probably worth editing your question to include the openRecordSet function. Also, have you checked whether the objConnection object is null or not when calling execute on it? I'd bet that would be your problem (and caused by an incorrect connection string).